# Windsor.Castle changes IHandler wheres .Service gone?

Tags: castle-windsor, mef

I have been working with the MEF and Windsor in a new project. I just updated my Windsor packages and my code breaks now. 
Where we use to have:

> from the MefContrib.Samples

```
 private void RegisterCastleComponent(IHandler handler)
 {
    var name = handler.ComponentModel.Name;
    var type = handler.Service;
    // By default, Windsor assigns implementation's full name for the key,
    // but for a default key we want to pass null instead
    if (handler.ComponentModel.Implementation.FullName == name)
    {
        name = null;
    }

       OnRegisteringComponent(type, name);
 }
```

Windsor doesnt have .Service in its IHandler in  Castle.Windsor.dll, v4.0.30319

How should i implement the above, then?

I can get a .Services which is IEnumerable. 
Should i just register them all, the first one? What are the implications?

Why there are .Services now?

Thanks

Actually, did go and check the BreakingChanges.txt:

====================================================================
change - Rebuilt how components exposing multiple services are handled internally. This includes
    several changes to the API:
    ForwardingHandler class and IHandlerFactory.CreateForwarding method were removed.
    ComponentModel.Service property was removed replaced with ClassService and InterfaceServices
    properties. Also AddService method was added. Constructor's argument for service was changed
    to be Type[] instead of single Type.
    IHandler.Service property was removed, replaced by Services property.
    IComponentModelBuilder.BuildModel method takes now ICollection isntead of single Type
    as services.
    ComponentRegistration.For(Type serviceType, params Type[] forwaredTypes) method was removed.
    ComponentFilter delegate type was removed as no longer needed

impact - low
fixability - easy

description - As part of improvement to internal architecture changed how components exposing 
    more than one service are handled.

fix - This change should not affect most users, unless extending internals of the container. If
    that's the case, adjust your calls to the new signatures, and change code anticipating ForwardedHandlers to use Services collection from the solve IHnadler for any given component ==========================================================================

I thikn it pretty much answers my question.

Or it doesnt:
Which would be the actual implementation? 
Getting the Services Name alog with its type? and do the checking against "handler.ComponentModel.Implementation.FullName" for the default key.

or just passed them as they are?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a bug and was reported on Dec 29th, 2011. Here is the ticket...  http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-three-a-testing-your-first-installer.ashx?HL=service,componentmodel&Discuss=1#MSG_20111228123958

Like you, I'm also wondering if there are any news on this?

Answer (score 0):

The `ComponentModel` type exposes both a `Service` and `Implementation` property, the latter denoting the implementation of the former. Can you use them to register your Windsor parts?

Comment: Thats what the problem seems to be. ComponentModel does NOT espose Service no more. Check the lastest Castle.Windsor.dll, v4.0.30319, hence the breakinChanges.txt excerpt. So in the new one, Implementation has many Services. Do you see my problem? Am I missing something really daft?

Comment: Lol, `IHandler` no longer exposes `Services`, but `IHandler.ComponentModel` should still?

Comment: slight correction, Service is not in IHandler and ComponentModel.Services is exposed, but there is no Service. SO How do you register the Types properly under the implementation?